# Memory problems parsing HTML from site

Tags: c#, html, sql

I have a infinate loop reading HTML from a site.
I tried parsing it using AgilityPack, but my machine slowed down over time and I had to stop the program when Task Manager showed it used 40 gigabytes.
So - I started parsing the HTML myself using split commands and indexof.

I put the data into a table and when the parsing is done I use a SqlBulkCopy to dump the data into the server.

I have tried both WriteToServer and WriteToServerAsync in the SqlBulkCopy.
I have also tried a wait(200) after each bulkcopy to give SQL Server some time.

Then I clear the table, clear the HTML string, the lists from the split and the loop starts over.

The program increases in size still. Not so fast as when using AgilityPack, but still I see running it for days will become a problem.

I want to mention that when I pause the program from Visual Studio, the size does not decrease. Telling me that giving SQL Server ( 2019 ) time does not help out.

Any ideas on why the program is increasing in size ? Or tips I can try to make it better?

UPDATE!
This is my infinate loop
CMCView is a WebView2

while (true)
{
string html = await CMCView.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.documentElement.outerHTML;");
string h = Regex.Replace(html,@"\u(?[a-zA-Z0-9]{4})",m => {return ((char)int.Parse(m.Groups["Value"].Value, NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToString();});

```
        HTMLDecoder hTMLDecoder = new HTMLDecoder(h);
        hTMLDecoder = null;
```

}

the HTMLDecoder is where i parse the h string and save to database.
The site has three windows I want to use : Indexes, Commodities and Currencies.
I find them by splitting the FeatureWindowController into lists of product-name-child.

To increase speed, I load the tables and put the ID and name in Dictionarys.
Then I loop the indexesRows, commodityRows and currencyRows.
I compare the name in the HTML with the name in the dictionary and add it if it is not there. I know - I will change it to parameters in the future, but I do not think that is the issue here.
In each of those loops I add to the History table. I clear it, clear the dictionary, load the table and load the dictionarys for each save.
And I add info to the History table.

After those three loops I use the SqlBulkCopy to save to database.

```
class HTMLDecoder
{
    DataTable indekserDataTable = new DataTable();
    DataTable commoditiesDataTable = new DataTable();
    DataTable valutaDataTable = new DataTable();
    DataTable countriesDataTable = new DataTable();
    DataTable marketTypesDataTable = new DataTable();
    DataTable productsDataTable = new DataTable();
    DataTable historyDataTable = new DataTable();

    Dictionary<string, int> countriesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    Dictionary<string, int> marketTypesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    Dictionary<string, int> productsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    public HTMLDecoder(string HTML)
    {
        HTMLDecoder_(HTML);
        HTML = string.Empty;
    }

    public async Task<string> HTMLDecoder_(string HTML)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatchstopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        Stopwatch stopwatchstopwatch1 = new Stopwatch();
        Task returnTask = null;

        indekserDataTable = LoadTable("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ISINDEX = 1");
        commoditiesDataTable = LoadTable("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ISCOMMODITY = 1");
        valutaDataTable = LoadTable("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ISCURRENCY= 1");
        countriesDataTable = LoadTable("SELECT * FROM COUNTRIES");
        marketTypesDataTable = LoadTable("SELECT * FROM MARKETTYPES");
        productsDataTable = LoadTable("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS");
        historyDataTable = LoadTable("SELECT TOP(0) * FROM HISTORY");

        setCountriesDictionary();
        setMarketTypesDictionary();
        setProductsDictionary();
        List<string> spl1 = HTML.Split(new string[] { "FeatureWindowController" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

        spl1.RemoveAt(0);
        List<string> indexesRows2 = spl1[2].Split(new string[] { "product-name-child" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        List<string> commoditiesRows2 = spl1[3].Split(new string[] { "product-name-child" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        List<string> currencyRows2 = spl1[1].Split(new string[] { "product-name-child" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        spl1.Clear();

        List<string> indexesRows = (from order in indexesRows2
                                    where (order.IndexOf("title") < 30 &&
                                    order.IndexOf("title") > -1)
                                    select order).ToList();

        List<string> commoditiesRows = (from order in commoditiesRows2
                                        where (order.IndexOf("title") < 30 &&
                                        order.IndexOf("title") > -1)
                                        select order).ToList();

        List<string> currencyRows = (from order in currencyRows2
                                        where (order.IndexOf("title") < 30 &&
                                        order.IndexOf("title") > -1)
                                        select order).ToList();

        #region  indekser
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (string ups2 in indexesRows)
        {
            counter++;
            bool error = false;
            DataRow newHistoryRow = historyDataTable.NewRow();
            newHistoryRow["DATE"] = DateTime.Now;
            newHistoryRow["TIME"] = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

            string ups = ups2.Replace("\\", "");
            List<string> list = ups.Split(new string[] { "title=" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

            string markettype = list[2].Substring(0, list[2].IndexOf("\"", 1)).Replace("\"", "");
            int marketTypeId = 0;
            bool marketTypeExists = marketTypesDictionary.ContainsKey(markettype);
            if (!marketTypeExists)
            {
                string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO MARKETTYPES (MarketTypeName) VALUES ('" + markettype + "')";
                ExecuteSQLNoResult(sqlQuery);
                marketTypesDataTable.Rows.Clear();
            marketTypesDataTable = LoadTable("SELECT * FROM MARKETTYPES");
                setMarketTypesDictionary();
            }
            marketTypesDictionary.TryGetValue(markettype, out marketTypeId);


            string productName = list[1].Substring(0, list[1].IndexOf("\"", 1)).Replace("\"", "");
            int productId = 0;
            bool productExists = productsDictionary.ContainsKey(productName);
            if (!productExists)
            {
                string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO PRODUCTS (PRODUCTNAME, MARKETTYPEID,  ISINDEX) VALUES ('" + productName + "', " + marketTypeId + ", 1)";
                ExecuteSQLNoResult(sqlQuery);
                productsDataTable.Rows.Clear();
                productsDataTable = LoadTable("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS");
                setProductsDictionary();
            }
            productsDictionary.TryGetValue(productName, out productId);
            newHistoryRow["PRODUCTID"] = productId;

            List<string> list2 = list[2].Split(new string[] { "span class=\"" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
            int countryStart = list2[2].IndexOf(">") + 1;
            int countryEnd = list2[2].IndexOf("<");
            string countryName = list2[2].Substring(countryStart, countryEnd - countryStart);
            #region insert Country if not Exists
            if (countryName.ToUpper() != "GLOBAL")
            {
                bool countryExists = countriesDictionary.ContainsKey(countryName);
                if (!countryExists)
                {
                    int isDevelopedMarket = 0;
                    int isEmergingMarket = 0;
                    if (markettype == "Utviklede markeder")
                        isDevelopedMarket = 1;
                    else
                        isEmergingMarket = 1;

                    string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO COUNTRIES (COUNTRYNAME, isDevelopedMarket, isEmergingMarket) VALUES ('" + countryName + "', " + isDevelopedMarket + ", " + isEmergingMarket + ")";
                    ExecuteSQLNoResult(sqlQuery);
                    countriesDataTable.Rows.Clear();
                    countriesDataTable = LoadTable("SELECT * FROM COUNTRIES");    
                    setCountriesDictionary();
                }
            }
            #endregion

            int percentageStart = list2[3].IndexOf(">") + 1;
            string percentage = list2[3].Substring(percentageStart, list2[3].IndexOf("<") - percentageStart).Replace(",", ".").Replace(" ", "").Replace("%", "").Trim();

            int numericStart = list2[4].IndexOf(">") + 1;
            string numeric = list2[4].Substring(numericStart, (list2[4].IndexOf("<") - numericStart)).Replace(",", ".").Replace(" ", "");
            if (numeric != "-")
            {
                try
                {
                    newHistoryRow["ChangeInPercent"] = percentage;
                    newHistoryRow["ChangeValue"] = numeric;
                }
                catch
                {
                    error = true;
                }
            }
            list2.Clear();
            string low = list[3].Substring(0, list[3].IndexOf("\"", 1)).Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", ".").Replace("\"", "");
            string high = list[4].Substring(0, list[4].IndexOf("\"", 1)).Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", ".").Replace("\"", "");
            string open = list[5].Substring(0, list[5].IndexOf("\"", 1)).Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", ".").Replace("\"", "");
            string close = list[6].Substring(0, list[6].IndexOf("\"", 1)).Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", ".").Replace("\"", "");

            List<string> string7 = list[7].Split(new string[] { "price-panel-button__label\"" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
            string sell = string7[1].Substring(1, string7[2].IndexOf("<") - 1).Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", ".");
            string buy = string7[2].Substring(1, string7[2].IndexOf("<") - 1).Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", ".");
            list.Clear();
            string7.Clear();

            if (low != "-")
            {
                try
                {
                    newHistoryRow["LOW"] = low;
                    newHistoryRow["HIGH"] = high;
                    newHistoryRow["OPEN"] = open;
                    newHistoryRow["CLOSE"] = close;
                    newHistoryRow["SELL"] = sell;
                    newHistoryRow["BUY"] = buy;
                }
                catch
                {
                    error = true;
                }
            }

            if (!error)
            {
                if (newHistoryRow[4].ToString().Length > 0)
                {
                    historyDataTable.Rows.Add(newHistoryRow);
                    newHistoryRow = historyDataTable.NewRow();
                }
            }
        }
        indexesRows.Clear();

        foreach (string ups2 in commoditiesRows)
        {
            counter++;
            bool error = false;
            DataRow newHistoryRow = historyDataTable.NewRow();
            newHistoryRow["DATE"] = DateTime.Now;
            newHistoryRow["TIME"] = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

            string ups = ups2.Replace("\\", "");
            List<string> list = ups.Split(new string[] { "title=" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        //List<string> list = ups.Split(new string[] { "title=\"" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        if (list.Count < 2)
        {
            continue;
        }
        string markettype = list[2].Substring(0, list[2].IndexOf("\"", 1)).Replace("\"", "");
        int marketTypeId = 0;
        bool marketTypeExists = marketTypesDictionary.ContainsKey(markettype);
        if (!marketTypeExists)
        {
            string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO MARKETTYPES (MarketTypeName) VALUES ('" + markettype + "')";
            ExecuteSQLNoResult(sqlQuery);
            marketTypesDataTable.Rows.Clear();
            marketTypesDataTable = LoadTable("SELECT * FROM MARKETTYPES");
            setMarketTypesDictionary();
        }
        marketTypesDictionary.TryGetValue(markettype, out marketTypeId);


        string productName = list[1].Substring(0, list[1].IndexOf("\"", 1)).Replace("\"", "");
        int productId = 0;
        bool productExists = productsDictionary.ContainsKey(productName);
        if (!productExists)
        {
            string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO PRODUCTS (PRODUCTNAME, MARKETTYPEID,  ISINDEX) VALUES ('" + productName + "', " + marketTypeId + ", 1)";
            ExecuteSQLNoResult(sqlQuery);
            productsDataTable.Rows.Clear();
            productsDataTable = LoadTable("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS");
            setProductsDictionary();
        }
        productsDictionary.TryGetValue(productName, out productId);
        newHistoryRow["PRODUCTID"] = productId;

        List<string> list2 = list[2].Split(new string[] { "span class=\"" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        int percentageStart = list2[3].IndexOf(">") + 1;
        string percentage = list2[3].Substring(percentageStart, list2[3].IndexOf("<") - percentageStart).Replace(",", ".").Replace(" ", "").Replace("%", "").Trim();

        int numericStart = list2[4].IndexOf(">") + 1;
        string numeric = list2[4].Substring(numericStart, (list2[4].IndexOf("<") - numericStart)).Replace(",", ".").Replace(" ", "");
        if (numeric != "-")
        {
            try
            {
                newHistoryRow["ChangeInPercent"] = percentage;
                newHistoryRow["ChangeValue"] = numeric;
            }
            catch
            {
                error = true;
            }
        }
        list2.Clear();
        string low = list[3].Substring(0, list[3].IndexOf("\"", 1)).Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", ".").Replace("\"", "");
        string high = list[4].Substring(0, list[4].IndexOf("\"", 1)).Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", ".").Replace("\"", "");
        string open = list[5].Substring(0, list[5].IndexOf("\"", 1)).Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", ".").Replace("\"", "");
        string close = list[6].Substring(0, list[6].IndexOf("\"", 1)).Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", ".").Replace("\"", "");

        List<string> string7 = list[7].Split(new string[] { "price-panel-button__label\"" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        string sell = string7[1].Substring(1, string7[2].IndexOf("<") - 1).Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", ".");
        string buy = string7[2].Substring(1, string7[2].IndexOf("<") - 1).Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", ".");
        list.Clear();
        string7.Clear();

        if (low != "-")
        {
            try
            {
                newHistoryRow["LOW"] = low;
                newHistoryRow["HIGH"] = high;
                newHistoryRow["OPEN"] = open;
                newHistoryRow["CLOSE"] = close;
                newHistoryRow["SELL"] = sell;
                newHistoryRow["BUY"] = buy;
            }
            catch
            {
                error = true;
            }
        }

        if (!error)
        {
            if (newHistoryRow[4].ToString().Length > 0)
            {
                historyDataTable.Rows.Add(newHistoryRow);
                newHistoryRow = historyDataTable.NewRow();
            }
        }
    }
    commoditiesRows.Clear();

    foreach (string ups2 in currencyRows)
    {
        counter++;
        bool error = false;
        DataRow newHistoryRow = historyDataTable.NewRow();
        newHistoryRow["DATE"] = DateTime.Now;
        newHistoryRow["TIME"] = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

        string ups = ups2.Replace("\\", "");
        List<string> list = ups.Split(new string[] { "title=" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        if (list.Count < 2)
        {
            continue;
        }
        string markettype = list[2].Substring(0, list[2].IndexOf("\"", 1)).Replace("\"", "");
        int marketTypeId = 0;
        bool marketTypeExists = marketTypesDictionary.ContainsKey(markettype);
        if (!marketTypeExists)
        {
            string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO MARKETTYPES (MarketTypeName) VALUES ('" + markettype + "')";
            ExecuteSQLNoResult(sqlQuery);
            marketTypesDataTable.Rows.Clear();
            marketTypesDataTable = LoadTable("SELECT * FROM MARKETTYPES");
            setMarketTypesDictionary();
        }
        marketTypesDictionary.TryGetValue(markettype, out marketTypeId);


        string productName = list[1].Substring(0, list[1].IndexOf("\"", 1)).Replace("\"", "");
        int productId = 0;
        bool productExists = productsDictionary.ContainsKey(productName);
        if (!productExists)
        {
            string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO PRODUCTS (PRODUCTNAME, MARKETTYPEID,  ISINDEX) VALUES ('" + productName + "', " + marketTypeId + ", 1)";
            ExecuteSQLNoResult(sqlQuery);
            productsDataTable.Rows.Clear();
            productsDataTable = LoadTable("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS");
            setProductsDictionary();
        }
        productsDictionary.TryGetValue(productName, out productId);
        newHistoryRow["PRODUCTID"] = productId;

        List<string> list2 = list[2].Split(new string[] { "span class=\"" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        int percentageStart = list2[3].IndexOf(">") + 1;
        string percentage = list2[3].Substring(percentageStart, list2[3].IndexOf("<") - percentageStart).Replace(",", ".").Replace(" ", "").Replace("%", "").Trim();
        if (percentage.Length < 2)
        {
        }

        int numericStart = list2[4].IndexOf(">") + 1;
        string numeric = list2[4].Substring(numericStart, (list2[4].IndexOf("<") - numericStart)).Replace(",", ".").Replace(" ", "");
        if (numeric != "-")
        {
            try
            {
                newHistoryRow["ChangeInPercent"] = percentage;
                newHistoryRow["ChangeValue"] = numeric;
            }
            catch
            {
                error = true;
            }
        }
        list2.Clear();

        string low = list[3].Substring(0, list[3].IndexOf("\"", 1)).Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", ".").Replace("\"", "");
        string high = list[4].Substring(0, list[4].IndexOf("\"", 1)).Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", ".").Replace("\"", "");
        string open = list[5].Substring(0, list[5].IndexOf("\"", 1)).Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", ".").Replace("\"", "");
        string close = list[6].Substring(0, list[6].IndexOf("\"", 1)).Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", ".").Replace("\"", "");

        List<string> string7 = list[7].Split(new string[] { "price-panel-button__label\"" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        string sell = string7[1].Substring(1, string7[2].IndexOf("<") - 1).Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", ".");
        string buy = string7[2].Substring(1, string7[2].IndexOf("<") - 1).Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", ".");
        list.Clear();
        string7.Clear();
        if (low != "-")
        {
            try
            {
                newHistoryRow["LOW"] = low;
                newHistoryRow["HIGH"] = high;
                newHistoryRow["OPEN"] = open;
                newHistoryRow["CLOSE"] = close;
                newHistoryRow["SELL"] = sell;
                newHistoryRow["BUY"] = buy;
            }
            catch
            {
                error = true;
            }
        }

        if (!error)
        {
            if (newHistoryRow[4].ToString().Length > 0)
            {
                historyDataTable.Rows.Add(newHistoryRow);
                newHistoryRow = historyDataTable.NewRow();
            }
        }
    }
    currencyRows.Clear();
    stopwatchstopwatch.Reset();
    stopwatchstopwatch.Start();

    using (SqlBulkCopy sqlbc = new SqlBulkCopy(SQLHelper.getSQLConnectionString()))
    {                    
        try
        {
            sqlbc.DestinationTableName = "HISTORY";
            await (returnTask = sqlbc.WriteToServerAsync(historyDataTable));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
    HTML = string.Empty; 
    stopwatchstopwatch.Stop();
    historyDataTable.Rows.Clear();
        
        
    #endregion

    return returnTask.ToString();
}






    public DataTable LoadTable(string SQLStatement)
    {
        var table = new DataTable();
        //Server = HAAKON; Database =SignalTrader; Trusted_Connection=True ;Trust Server Certificate=true   Server = HAAKON
        using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(SQLStatement, SQLHelper.getSQLConnectionString()))
        {
            da.Fill(table);
        }
        return table;
    }

    public void ExecuteSQLNoResult(string SQLStatement)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new(SQLHelper.getSQLConnectionString()))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQLStatement, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setCountriesDictionary()
    {
        countriesDictionary.Clear();
        countriesDictionary = countriesDataTable.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary<DataRow, string, int>(row => row.Field<string>(1), row => row.Field<int>(0));
    }

    private void setMarketTypesDictionary()
    {
        marketTypesDictionary.Clear();
        marketTypesDictionary = marketTypesDataTable.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary<DataRow, string, int>(row => row.Field<string>(1), row => row.Field<int>(0));
    }

    private void setProductsDictionary()
    {
        productsDictionary.Clear();
        productsDictionary = productsDataTable.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary<DataRow, string, int>(row => row.Field<string>(1), row => row.Field<int>(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect that it the code on the fifth line that is using up all the memory. If you change that everything will work real fast.

Comment: The fifth line as in : 

Then I clear the table, clear the HTML string, the lists from the split and the loop starts over. 

?

Well - actually I added that to see if manual cleaning would help. The problems were there before I started cleaning and setting strings to string.Empty; 

Thank you for responding to me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I did say the fifth line of your code, not the question!!!!

I was not being serious, you cannot just say that you have a problem with your application & expect anyone to be able to help you. We have no idea if the problem is with your code (because we cannot see it) or whether it is the site you are trying to parse (because we cannot see it).

What have you tried so far to locate the source of your problem? Have you tried parsing a different site or used test data to make sure the issue is with your code or with the HTML you are parsing?

Comment: setting the string h to string.Empty after hTMLDecoder = null; soved it. 

Thanks for trying to help out, folks.